# How to using custom footer temple while binding field?It say Id undefined,but id is my table property

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

How do I use a custom footer template while binding to a field? It says

> studentId undefined

but `studentId` is my table property.

My code's like this:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.studentId);
columns.Bound(p => p.Point)
.ClientGroupFooterTemplate("<div>average: #=kendo.toString(getPointby(studentId),'n0')  #</div><div>max: #= max #</div><div>min: #= min #</div>");
```

Comment: `.ClientGroupFooterTemplate` should be defined for the column that you are grouping and, afaik, you cannot define custom grouping function so you can use a function but you have no exposure to group data then you have to remove that `studentId`.